# What are best way to handle jQuery ajax asynchronous calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, design-patterns, asynchronous

I recently started on a project which uses heavy client side jQuery/javascripts. I am struggling to get one of the screen working.

I have function like below:

```
function init{
  populateTypes();
  populateGroups();
  populateStatuses();
  applyCurrentUserSettings();
}
```

All `populate*` methods make ajax calls (`$.ajax`) to server and poluate some checkbox lists on the view. `applyCurrentUserSettings` method also makes an ajax request and set the current user selection on the view.

The problem is `populate*` methods are asynchronous and by the `applyCurrentUserSettings` method is called, the checkboxlist are empty "sometimes" and the apply method fails.

I can get this work by passing `async: false` in the `$.ajax` calls, or chain each ajax call inside another, but I would like to know if there are any better ways/design patterns to handle such scenario.

Comment: Use callbacks to make sure that functions which depend on others are always run in sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make all your functions to return deferreds and use `$.when`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
function populateTypes () {
    //your code
    return $.ajax(...);
}


$.when(populateTypes(), populateGroups(), ...).then(applyCurrentUserSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use ajaxComplete() to delay the trigger of `applyCurrentUserSettings` until the queries are done.

Answer (score 0):

Build your functions so that they properly return promise objects, then use the .then method to chain multiple one after the other, or the .when method to send off x number of them, then do something when all of those are complete.

```
function populateTypes () {
    //your code
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

the following sends them 1 at a time:

```
function init () {
    populateTypes().then(populateGroups)
        .then(populateStatuses)
        .then(applyCurrentUserSettings)
        .done(function(){
            console.log("all done");
        });
}
```

the following sends all but the last one at once, and the last once when the previous three are done:

```
function init () {
    $.when(populateTypes(), populateGroups(), populateStatuses())
        .then(applyCurrentUserSettings)
        .done(function(){
            console.log("all done");
        });
}
```